# Pytest+FastAPI+SQLAlchemy+Postgres: ошибка InterfaceError

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi

Разрабатывая апп на FastAPI, SQLAlchemy и PostgreSQL встретил ошибки при организации тестирования (однако с SQLite всё работает). [Сделал репо с минимальной версией аппа и тестированием через Pytest на Docker Compose](https://github.com/AivanF/Postgres-SQLAlchemy-FastAPI-problem).

Основная ошибка – `sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError('cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress')`. Подозреваю, что оно связано с иницилизацией приложения/БД, хотя я проверил, что всё происходит последовательно. Также пробовал использовать единственный экземпляр `TestClient` для всех тест-кейсов, но это не помогло. Надеюсь найти решение и грамотный способ такого тестирования

Самые важные куски кода:

### app.py:

```py
app = FastAPI()
some_items = dict()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    await create_database()
    # Extract some data from env, local files, or S3
    some_items["pi"] = 3.1415926535
    some_items["eu"] = 2.7182818284

@app.post("/{name}")
async def create_obj(name: str, request: Request):
    data = await request.json()
    if data.get("code") in some_items:
        data["value"] = some_items[data["code"]]
        async with async_session() as session:
            async with session.begin():
                await create_object(session, name, data)
        return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content=data)
    else:
        return JSONResponse(status_code=404, content={})

@app.get("/{name}")
async def get_connected_register(name: str):
    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            objects = await get_objects(session, name)
    result = []
    for obj in objects:
        result.append({
            "id": obj.id, "name": obj.name, **obj.data,
        })
    return result
```

### tests.py:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()

@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="module")
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def get_db():
    await delete_database()
    await create_database()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_case", test_cases_post)
def test_post(get_db, test_case):
    with TestClient(app)() as client:
        response = client.post(f"/{test_case['name']}", json=test_case["data"])
        assert response.status_code == test_case["res"]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_case", test_cases_get)
def test_get(get_db, test_case):
    with TestClient(app)() as client:
        response = client.get(f"/{test_case['name']}")
        assert len(response.json()) == test_case["count"]
```

### db.py:

```py
DATABASE_URL = environ.get("DATABASE_URL", "sqlite+aiosqlite:///./test.db")
engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, future=True, echo=True)
async_session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)
Base = declarative_base()

async def delete_database():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)

async def create_database():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)


class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = "smth"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    data = Column(JSON, nullable=False)
    idx_main = Index("name", "id")

async def create_object(db: Session, name: str, data: dict):
    connection = Model(name=name, data=data)
    db.add(connection)
    await db.flush()

async def get_objects(db: Session, name: str):
    raw_q = select(Model) \
        .where(Model.name == name) \
        .order_by(Model.id)
    q = await db.execute(raw_q)
    return q.scalars().all()
```